# Синонимия беспредложных и предложных конструкций

Tags: стилистика, управление, смысл

> Чудесна сцена встречи груженых машин одного колхоза, на которых едут девушки, с молодыми казаками из другого колхоза. [Розенталь Д.Э., Практическая стилистика русского языка (Изд. 5-е), 1987]

В этом предложении есть стилистическая ошибка. Мое объяснение ошибки: машины главнее девушек, а девушки - это груз.

Мое исправление ошибки в предложении.

**Чудесна сцена встречи машин девушек одного колхоза с молодыми казаками из другого колхоза.**

Как считаете, правильно ли? Я изменил управление с предложной формы в беспредложную форму.
Заранее, благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обоих предложениях происходит встреча машин и казаков, что стилистически не красиво. Это предложение верно описывает факты, но смещает акцент с девушек на машины. Правильно так:

> Чудесна сцена встречи девушек одного колхоза, едущих на грузовых машинах, с молодыми казаками из другого колхоза.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! А если казаки тоже на машинах? Т.е, "груженые". В том то и проблема, ведь непонятно, на чем казаки.

Comment: В любом случае у нас должна быть встреча либо казаков с девушками, либо в крайнем случае машин с машинами. Если казаки точно на машинах, то можно сказать: Чудесна сцена встречи машин с казаками одного колхоза и машин с девушками из другого колхоза.

Comment: Понятно. Значит, двузначность в отношении формы встречи (встреча машин, либо встреча людей) выглядит некрасиво. Спасибо!

Comment: @РустамМулюков *А если казаки тоже на машинах?* Никаких "если". Казаки там на конях.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5OY3HuYegg&list=PLNOGWj6ZSmt5ZuF4RbJMkRLWPtwa2JlW7&index=114 (15:00 примерно - и дальше). А машины гружёные не девушками, а арбузами. Впрочем, это не единственное, что мне не нравится в ваших вариантах правки, но сейчас не могу подробно. Чуть позже отвечу.

Answer (score 1):

Если не жертвовать точностью в угоду стилистике, то правка представляется примерно такой.

***Чудесна сцена встречи девушек одного колхоза, едущих на груженых машинах, с молодыми казаками из другого колхоза.***

Это тоже не шедевр изящной словесности, причастный оборот не до конца устраняет всю тяжеловесность исходной фразы, но по крайней мере это в точности то, что имел сказать автор.

Подробности (при необходимости) - позже.

> Чудесна сцена встречи машин девушек одного колхоза с молодыми казаками
> из другого колхоза.

А это никуда не годится. Что еще за "машины девушек"?!

Comment: Да, признаю ошибку свою. Я забыл, что машины груженые (т.е, грузовые). В приведенном мною варианте я хотел сказать, что машина принадлежит девушкам и думал, что принадлежность подразумевает их наличие в машине...